# High Order Components with multiple childrens

Tags: reactjs

How I can create a HOC that has this kind of form

```
<HOC>
  <HOC.Header>
    Header
  </HOC.Header>
  <HOC.Footer>
    Footer
  </HOC.Footer>
</HOC>
```

And how are Footer and Header childs passed to the HOC component/hook?
Thanks for answering!

Comment: What makes this a higher order component? Or are you saying that `HOC` is already a higher order component but you don't know how to make it accept children?

Comment: Hi, HOC is already a High Order Component. My terrible described question, was about, how make it accept the children. Thx

Comment: AFAIK a HOC is just a component that gets dynamically defined but that doesn't change how the component works in general. It still works like any other component and therefore you access children in exactly the same way as in a normal component.